# Strange grep behaviour on fish shell

Tags: regex, shell, grep, fish

```
cat > abc.txt <<EOF
2014-04-11 00:00:00
2014-02-19 00:22:00
EOF
```

When I execute

```
grep -E :[0-9]{2}: abc.txt
```

I get

```
2014-02-19 00:22:00
```

I was expecting

```
2014-04-11 00:00:00
2014-02-19 00:22:00
```

This happens on fish shell (2.4.0), on bash it works fine. I am quite intrigued with whats going on here

Comment: Try quoting `:[0-9]{2}:` so that it doesn't get expanded by the shell

Comment: If your question can be answered only by someone who's an expert in fish, don't tag bash as well; the general rule is that expertise in a tagged area should be reasonably expected to be helpful towards answering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fish `{a,b,c}` is an enumerator. Example of use from the documentation:

```
$ echo input.{c,h,txt}
input.c input.h input.txt
```

So, your regular expression expands as `:[0-9]2:`:

```
$ echo :[0-9]{2}:
:[0-9]2:
$ echo :[0-9]{2,3,4}:
:[0-9]2: :[0-9]3: :[0-9]4:
```

Escape the curly braces to avoid this:

```
$ echo :[0-9]\{2\}:
:[0-9]{2}:
```

Or, as suggested by Fredrik, quote the whole regular expression:

```
$ echo ':[0-9]{2}:'
:[0-9]{2}:
```